# join multiple rows with single entry

Tags: sql, database, join

The goal is to get all related information in a single row. The event table contains contacts and locations in their respective tables. The relations are stored in a table called eventrelation, where there are parent (event) and child (contact,location) references.

The tables are as follows:

```
1. event : id ...
2. contact : id ...
3. location : id ...

eventrelation : pid | cid | p_type | c_type
pid = foreign key (event.id)
cid = id of contact or location
p_type && c_type are type of data shown as no above
i.e. 1:event, 2:contact, 3:location
```

All the associated contact & location info related to one event could be returned in the same row as that event. To get that I tried the following query (with error)

```
SELECT E.ID, C.ID, L.ID
FROM EVENT E
LEFT OUTER JOIN EVENTRELATION ER ON E.ID=ER.PID
LEFT OUTER JOIN CONTACT C ON ER.CID=C.ID AND ER.C_TYPE=2
LEFT OUTER JOIN LOCATION L ON ER.CID=L.ID AND ER.C_TYPE=3
```

The tables contained the following data (for example purposes)

```
EVENT   CONTACT   LOCATION
ID      ID        ID
1       1         1
2       2
3

EVENTRELATION DATA
P | C | PT | CT
1   1   1    2   --> event1 with contact1
1   1   1    3   --> event1 with location1
2   1   1    2   --> event2 with contact1
```

the result of the query was :

```
RESULT
E | C | L
1   1   #
1   #   1
2   1   #
3   #   #
```

I get errors with getting the contact and location in a single row, whereas in the current example, they come up as different rows. The ideal results should be as :

```
RESULT
E | C | L
1   1   1
2   1   #
3   #   #
```

Which step in creating the joins is wrong here?

Comment: Downvote because the question is very badly written.

Comment: I have edited the question to try and make it more clear, is it still unreadable?